# Data between years using select query in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want data between years using select query in MS Access in VB.NET.

My code is:

```
 Try
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim rpt As New rptLedger()
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim MyCommand As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim myDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim myDS As New DataSet 'The DataSet you created.

    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnString)
    MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Ledger.rdate, Ledger.pDate, Ledger.receipttotal, Ledger.PaymentTotal, Ledger.PartyName, Ledger.CompCode, Ledger.Cmpcode, Ledger.rnarration, Ledger.pnarration FROM Ledger where pDate >= dateadd(year,-1,GETD())"
    MsgBox(MyCommand.CommandText)
    MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
    myDA.Fill(myDS, "Ledger")


    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    myConnection.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: i want year wise data in reports using select query in vb,net

Comment: Can you tell us what you get? An error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need Access functions and syntax:

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Ledger.rdate, Ledger.pDate, Ledger.receipttotal, Ledger.PaymentTotal, Ledger.PartyName, Ledger.CompCode, Ledger.Cmpcode, Ledger.rnarration, Ledger.pnarration FROM Ledger where pDate >= DateAdd('yyyy', -1, Date())"
```